# Deployment Of Laravel 5.6 project to shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, laravel-5.6

I have a major problem during the deployment of my laravel 5.6 project on shared hosting, It seems my blades are not going to work. I have copied all of my project files to a new folder in my root directory namely "muxproject" and then I coppied all of the files in public folder of laravel project to public_html, and i have changed the index.php file as follows

```
<?php
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/../muxproject/vendor/autoload.php'; //changed

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../muxproject/bootstrap/app.php'; //changed

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When I navigate to the link http://example.com/ A login page according to my logic in web.php appear and ask for the login after login successfully the user is redirected to the link http://example.com/home no issue still here but when I navigate to http://example.com/register nothing load except my header, footer, and sidebar my registration page does not appear. the same is the case with http://example.com/branch and http://example.com/userbranch 
following is the code for my web.php file

```
<?php

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function (){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/branch','Branch\BranchController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/userbranch','Branch\UserBranchController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/course', 'Course\CourseMasterController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/coursedetail','Course\CourseDetailController@index')->name('idex');
    Route::get('/studentenquiry','Enquiry\StudentEnquiryController@index')->name('index');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
        return view('home');
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('delete/{id}','Auth\RegisterController@destroy');
Route::patch('update','Auth\RegisterController@update')->name('update');

Route::patch('/update/branch','Branch\BranchController@update')->name('update');
Route::post('/storebranch','Branch\BranchController@store')->name('store');
Route::post('/storebranchuser', 'Branch\UserBranchController@store')->name('store');
Route::get('/delete/branch/{id}','Branch\BranchController@destroy');
Route::get('/userbranch/delete/{id}', 'Branch\UserBranchController@destroy');
Route::patch('/update/userbranch','Branch\UserBranchController@update')->name('update');
Route::post('/storecourse','Course\CourseMasterController@store')->name('store');
Route::get('delete/course/{id}','Course\CourseMasterController@destroy');
Route::patch('update/course', 'Course\CourseMasterController@update')->name('update');
```

Following is the code for RegisterUsersController to show the registration form

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $userData = \App\User::all();
        return view('auth.register',compact('userData'));
    }

@section('content')
 //
@endsection
```

the content between here in my blades register.blade.php, branch.blade.php and
userbranch.blade.php is not working and I am having just empty page except header, footer and sidebar just on shared hosting Each and everything works fine on local

Below is the code for .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me in this regard, I have gone through a lot of tutorials and I just figured out that for some reason the code in between @section('content') is not loading;

Comment: Well looks like you are using it in totally wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you have copied files and pasted in shared hosting and changed default files of laravel?**

**I think you should read this answer and understand and then deploy your project**

**You can do it in 2 ways**

**First way** (recommended but time taking to learn):

1-You should learn how to use **[git (version control system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)**. when you learn about it then you will be able to save your laravel project on a git server. while learning git you will read about **clone** it will let you download your project from git to any server, any computer. It can be difficult to understand at first but believe me it is very useful and you should use it. visit [github.com](https://github.com/) , [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com)  or [bitbucket.com](https://bitbucket.org/).

2- when you have learnt how to use git then save your code to git. Then use **git bash (for windows)** or use **terminal for mac/linux** these are command line tools. Using it you can connect to your server where you want host your site. login using **ssh** to shared hosting server and go to public_html and **clone your laravel prpject there**. After cloning,**go to project direcrtory** create **.env** file and change it according to your settings, then run composer install (it will install all packages that your project requires). Then set root directory of your laravel project to your domain using **cpanel** and hit domain. You should be able to see your laravel working

**Second way:**(NOT recommended but quick)

1. Copy project folder except vendor folder to shared hosting server
2. open your pc terminal, connect to server, go to laravel project directory, install laravel.
3. set domain to your laravel project root directory and hit domain

Comment: Dear, I am very well known to git, further in shared hosting We don't have ssh access. Please let me what should I do in this regard.

Comment: get SSH access and install laravel using either method I mentioned in answer you like. Otherwise environment issues will erase

Comment: The way you are using is not recommended. It will waste your time

Comment: Dear I have tried by all means installed laravel throghg softacolas but same result, my form is not loading

Comment: Don't waste your time to install laravel like this. Best solution is ssh access get it somehow and do what you want.Otherwise many packages will erase issues due to different versions of environment